# Help me understand this antiderivative

Tags: calculus, integration

I have a simple equation I typed into WolframAlpha to see what it was. Look what WO gave me:

> Indefinite integrals:
>   $$
> \int \frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}} du = \sqrt{u} + \text{constant}.
> $$
>   Possible intermediate steps:
>   $$
> \int \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{u}} du
> $$
>   Factor out constants:
>   $$
> \frac 1 2 \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}} du
> $$
>   The integral of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}$ is $2\sqrt{u}$:
>   $$
> \sqrt{u} + \text{constant}
> $$

Is this so?  How can the antiderivative of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}$ be $2 \sqrt{u}$?

*Edit [by SN]: Added the steps given by Wolfram|Alpha to the question, and removed the  link to the screenshot image.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}$ as $u^{-\frac{1}{2}}$. Now you can just apply the power rule (i.e. increase the exponent rule by 1 and divide by the new exponent). This gives
$$
\begin{align*}
\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}} \, du &= \int u^{-\frac{1}{2}} \, du\\
&= \frac{u^\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1}{2}} + C\\
&= 2 \sqrt{u} + C.
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Ah nuts.  I was getting confused with the derivative rules.  I mixed them up.  Duh moment.  Thanks. I'll accept when I can. 
:)

Answer (score 1):

Check it with $\frac{d}{du} (\sqrt{u}+C)$.

Comment: That derivative evaluates to $0$. :)